# Difference between two indicator functions

Tags: functions, logic, boolean-algebra

I have an indicator function $\mathbb{1}(A)$ that equals to one if A is true. I am interested in simplifying the following difference between indicator functions:

$$ \mathbb{1}\left\{\sum_{j^{\prime}\neq j }d_{j^{\prime}}^{*} +  d_{j}^{*}  > 0\right\} - \mathbb{1}\left\{\sum_{j^{\prime}\neq j }d_{j^{\prime}}^{*} + \hat{d_{j}}> 0\right\} $$

so, for $j^{\prime}\neq j$ both summations contain the same terms and the difference between both arguments is for entry $j$. Moreover, for all j, $d_{j} \in \{0,1\}$.

I am wondering if the following factorization of this expression is correct:

$$ \mathbb{1}\left\{\sum_{j^{\prime}\neq j }d_{j^{\prime}}^{*} +  d_{j}^{*}  > 0\right\} - \mathbb{1}\left\{\sum_{j^{\prime}\neq j }d_{j^{\prime}}^{*} + \hat{d_{j}}> 0\right\} = \left(1 -  \mathbb{1}\left\{\sum_{j^{\prime}\neq j }d_{j^{\prime}}^{*}> 0\right\}\right)\left( d_{j}^{*} - \hat{d_{j}}  \right) $$

I have been thinking all day about a more synthetic way to write this expression. If someone can help me, I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Certainly false without some assumption on $d_j^{*}$ and $\hat {d_j}$. Do you know that these numbers also belong to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Yes! All of the $d$ are either 0s or 1s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy do you have any other insight?